# How to create new custom database as core master and web in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to create new custom database in Sitecore is there any way to do

Comment: Hi Monit and welcome to Sitecore community. Please elaborate more on your query as it is too wide. Why you need custom database? Do you want to use Sitecore API to access it? What you would like to store there? What kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="www.sitecore.net/.../">
<sitecore>
<eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">
<eventQueueProvider>
<eventQueue name="preview" patch:after="evertQueue[@name='web']" type="Sitecore.Data.Eventing.$(database)EventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
<param ref="PropertyStoreProvider/store[@name='$(name)']" />
</eventQueue>
</eventQueueProvider>
</eventing>
<PropertyStoreProvider>
<store name="preview" patch:after="store[@name='web']" prefix="preview" getValueWithoutPrefix="true" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Properties.$(database)PropertyStore, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param ref="dataApis/dataApi[@name='$(database)']" param1="$(name)" />
<param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseEventManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
<param resolve="true" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseCacheManager, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</store>
</PropertyStoreProvider>
<databases>
<database id="preview" patch:after="database[@id='web']" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param desc="name">$(id)</param>
<icon>Images/database_web.png</icon>
<securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
<dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
<dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
<disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
<prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config" />
</prefetch>
</dataProvider>
</dataProviders>
<proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
<proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)" />
<archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
<archive name="archive" />
<archive name="recyclebin" />
</archives>
<cacheSizes hint="setting">
<data>100MB</data>
<items>50MB</items>
<paths>2500KB</paths>
<itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
<standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
</cacheSizes>
</database>
</databases>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

For this we need to follow the below steps :

1. We need to open a SQL server and copy web or another database (related to your project) that you want to copy and rename it, in my case, I renamed it to "**preview**". Example: SitecoreWebsite_Web to SitecoreWebsite_Preview.
2. Now, you need to create a patch file and add the above code to it. I want to add the above code after the web database node so I am adding "`patch:after`".
3. You need to create a connection string to the new database in `connectionstrings.config`(path for the connection string `your_website_instance_name\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config`) copy any existing connection string and update it. Example :

```xml
<add name="preview" connectionString="___update your server details here..."/>
```

4. You need to create an item for a new database in the content tree at the path `/sitecore/system/Publishing targets` and in "Target database" field type your database name(in my case preview)
5. you can add indexes for the newly created database.
6. After all these steps newly created database will show on the right side at the bottom of the Sitecore desktop.

Hope this helps you !!!

**Updated :-**

Above mentioned patch file will change according to your database config file. You can check config file under `Sitecore.config` file for adding existing database name.